# java.io.FileNotFoundException while posting image from Gallery to server

Tags: java, android, multipartform-data

I want to post image selected through camera to server using multi part .I am getting exception here

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/26: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Code is given below:

```
//On clicking Gallery
layout_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        loadImageFromGallery();
    }
});

public void loadImageFromGallery() {
    popupWindow.dismiss();
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    Log.e("root", root);
    String directory_path = root + "/cam_intent/";
    File myDir = new File(directory_path);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(myDir, "MyPhoto.jpg");
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.e("Uri of File", String.valueOf(fileUri));
    galleryIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}
    
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            launchUploadActivity(true);
        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG) {
            fileUri = data.getData();
            //File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(NewGroupActivity.this,uri));
            //fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Log.e("FileUriImageGallery", String.valueOf(fileUri));
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.groupPic);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }           
}
```

Image is shown in the `ImageView` but is not sent to the server as it is thrown a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
private String uploadFile() {
    Log.e("upload File", "called");
    String responseString = null;
    
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Log.e("URL", url_create_new_group);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_create_new_group);
    
    try {
        AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void transferred(long num) {
                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
            }
        });
    
    
        // Adding file data to http body
        if (val == 0) {
            if (fileUri != null) {
                Log.e("val = ", String.valueOf(val));
                File sourceFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                if (sourceFile != null) {
                    Log.e("SoureFile", String.valueOf(sourceFile));
                    photosize = 0;
                    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                } else {
                    photosize = 1;
                    Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, "Please Upload Your Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            File sourceFile = new File(picturePath);
            if (sourceFile != null) {
                photosize = 0;
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            } else {
                photosize = 1;
                Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, "Please Upload Your Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
        Log.e("Total Size", String.valueOf(totalSize));
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
    
        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
    
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // Server response
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        } else {
            responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
        }
    
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    }
    
    return responseString;    
}
```

Please check the code.

---

#### Solved

**Updated Working Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            launchUploadActivity(true);
        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG) {
            Uri uri  = data.getData();
            //File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(NewGroupActivity.this,uri));
            //fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Log.e("FileUriImageGallery", String.valueOf(uri));
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.groupPic);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what your `Log.e("Uri of File", String.valueOf(fileUri));` line is showing at logcat?

Comment: E/Uri of File﹕ file:///storage/sdcard0/cam_intent/MyPhoto.jpg

Comment: Which line is throwing exception?

Comment: Thanks for your concern.It is working now.I was doing some silly mistakes.Please check my edited working code .

Comment: I am not getting any option to flag it as Solved .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105108/discussion-between-deepakr-and-talha).

Comment: Post your solution as a proper answer.